# Phantom transaction killing ActiveRecord? Rails can't read any data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, rubymine

When I start a console or start my project in development, I get this error whenever I try to touch my postgres db, but the file referred to in the error message no longer exists in my project.  (...app.workflows/user_workflow) . I changed the name of the file as well as the class name to intuit_user_workflow.rb and IntuitWorkflow respectively

```
 bash -c "/Users/yus3/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.5.0 do /Users/yus3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby /Users/yus3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta6/bin/rdebug-ide --key-value --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 49430 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 49431 -- \"/Users/yus3/Documents/Mac 11.18/RubymineProjects/CostReportQB/bin/rails\" console"
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.0.beta6, debase 0.2.3.beta2, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:49430
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.1)
2.5.0 :001 > >> p=Project.first
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
SyntaxError (/Users/yus3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:257: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_end
...app/workflows/user_workflow.rb:19
...                              ^
/Users/yus3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:273: dynamic constant assignment
        NULL_TRANSACTION = NullTransaction.new
                         ^
/Users/yus3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:283: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end)
2.5.0 :002 >
```

This whenever I try to do anything that requires activerecord.  fails with a similar looking set of error messages.

The odd thing is that the only file referred to which is not part of any library ...app/workflows/user_work.rb:19 is no longer in my project (although it used to be).  I  changed the name of the file and class to IntuitUserWorkflow everywhere it occurs in my project, which I confirmed by a thorough seardch of my code base.  Nevertheless I still get this error based on a non-existing file.  The other issue worth noting is that in the file I had the statement User.transaction do..end block used to be in the file before I renamed but I deleted the transaction code as well.

Here are some things I tried to do to address the problem.

- Restarted the server
- Quit the dev environment, invalidated the    caches, restarted
- Rebooted my machine
- Attempted to delete and recreate the db with
  rake db:drop (db:drop failed with simialr error)

  - Stopped and restarted postgres
  - Cleaned and rebundled all the gems.

I also was able to directly access the db without rails via sql console.  No problem there.

Environment is Rails 5.2.1 Ruby 2.5 Activerecord-5.2.1

Suggested remedies?

Comment: Any Active Jobs that might reference `UserWorkflow`? Or maybe STI things? Polymorphic associations?

Comment: There are no active jobs,but maybe more to the point UserWorkflow doesn’t exist.   It was just a Plain Ruby class not a actuverecord descendant, but it is name changed to IntuitUserWorkflow as is the file name changed as well.

Comment: You're sure you don't have a `user_workflow.rb` file anywhere? I'm asking about Active Jobs and the like because they can contain hidden references to class names.

Comment: I'm certain of it.  I checked it in finder from the root of my machine just to make certain.  That's what I find so weird.  I thought maybe there was a file in one of the gems also called user_workflow.rb, but certainly there is nothing in app/workflows by that name.

Comment: In fact I even checkout the prior version from the local git repo, which was before Ieven created the file 'user_workflow.rb' (which I subsequently renamed intuit_user_workflow.rb') . Same result!

Comment: The only way I could fix this was to start a whole new project on my machine, reload everything and then clone the repo.  Still kind of mystery.  Thanks mu

Comment: You're welcome, I guess. I wonder if RubyMine is up to something. But, you're probably better off just quietly moving on and pretending this never happened ;)

Comment: I think you'r eprobably right.  I suspect maybe the file name hanging around in one those files in .idea or something.